# Bad credentials

Tags: magento2, error

I'm getting a '***Bad Credentials***' error message when I try to upgrade from 2.3.0 -> 2.3.2 when a submit the access keys from the Web Wizard on the admin.

I think I read that these keys should be the same as when Magento was installed?

I didn't know this when I begun trying to upgrade my version and have deleted any previous access keys I may of had. Could this be the cause of my '***Bad credentials***' error message?

Comment: I guess No. I tried my Magento upgrades by using different account credentials and it works. Have you tried by regenerating those keys or look into the auth.json file if you saved keys previously when installing Magento?

Comment: I couldn't see a auth.json file in my server directories. I'm only getting the error message since I added a Curl.php file. Before I added the Curl.php file I got an HTTP/2 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are not able to upgrade Magento version by admin then you can try with command line or CLI here is the commands to upgrade with CLI :

- php bin/magento maintenance:enable
- composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 --no-update
- composer update
- rm -rf var/cache/
- rm -rf var/page_cache/
- rm -rf var/generation/
- chmod +x bin/magento
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento maintenance:disable

Comment: I went through the process above and had no issues. And it first appeared it worked as I had long loading times when accessing my site but on the backend on the dashboard page at the bottom it says Magento ver. 2.3.0. Should this now say 2.3.2?

Comment: yes, it should say 2.3.2
if it isn't working for you can follow the steps from here : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html it should work